# Selection of text in QTextBrowser using mousePressEvent() and mouseReleaseEvent()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

I have a `QTextBrowser` and I want to select a part of the text inside, I need the position of the start and the end of the selection. I want to do that with `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`. Here is my code,

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, TeamInsight.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    def set_text(self):
        self.textBrowser.setText('test strings are here')
```

textBrowser is inside a MainWindow. How do I implement `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` for text in textBrowser

Comment: QTextBrowser already implements text selection by mouse. Why do you want to implement it again?

Comment: I want to trigger another method when selected string positions are equal to specific values.

Comment: okay, I understand, when you say *I need the position of the start and the end of the selection*, what types of units do you mean, to pixels?

Comment: I mean the positions of the starting character and the ending character of the selection. For an example: suppose string is 'test' . Postion of the letter 'e' is 1. Position of the 's' is 2.

Comment: `self.browserInput.selectionChanged.connect(self.position)

def position(self):
        start = self.browserInput.textCursor().selectionStart()
        end   = self.browserInput.textCursor().selectionEnd()`
This code gives me a partial solution. But it gives multiple values when I do the selection.

Comment: suppose I select 'es' in 'test'. 
It gives values as:
1, 1 and 
1, 2
Because that signal is called each time I select a character and not when I press the mouse and the end of the selection.

Comment: If I understand you, check my answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to track events and you can not overwrite the class, the solution is to install an event filter, in your case, just the `MouseButtonRelease` event, we must filter the `viewport()` of the `QTextBrowser`:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

import TeamInsight


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, TeamInsight.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.browserInput.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.browserInput.setText("some text")

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.browserInput.viewport():
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                if self.browserInput.textCursor().hasSelection():
                    start = self.browserInput.textCursor().selectionStart()
                    end = self.browserInput.textCursor().selectionEnd()
                    print(start, end)
            elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                print("event mousePressEvent")
        return QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much @eyllanesc. This gave me the solution.